# Open all files (including hidden) in vi

Tags: vim, load

I have a file structure like so

```
/foo/bar/
├── .foo.cfg
├── foo.cfg
├── foo.data
├── foo.py
├── .svn
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
├── .
└── ..
```

I want to open all of the hidden and non hidden files into vim. I could do it manually like so

```
vi .foo.cfg foo.cfg foo.data foo.py
```

but that doesn't work when there are 100+ files. I have also tried the following with no success

```
#hidden files not loaded
vi *

#Includes folders and '.' and '..'
vi * .*

#loads files one at a time
for i in `ls -a` ; do vi $i; done;

#loads files one at a time
find . -name "*" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec vi {} ";"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec vi {} +
```

From the `find` man page:

> ```
>    -exec command {} +
> ```
>
> This variant of the -exec option runs the specified command on the selected files,  but  the command  line  is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The  command line  is  built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of ’{}’ is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.

Comment: well it worked, but I got `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` and then it locked my shell upon leaving `vim`

Comment: actually, it didn't lock it, just that nothing is being printed, and if i press enter, there is no new line character between additional command lines

Comment: @puk - I noticed the same odd behavior when I tested it, see my edit, it should work correctly now without the side effects.

Comment: I don't think the `-name "*"` is necessary.

Comment: @SamBrinck - Thanks, removed that from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be

```
vim $(find . -type f)
```

note that this opens all files in the current folder, doing the same for files in the folders of the current folder. You can also try

```
vim * .[^.]*
```

this won't open `.` or `..` because it doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Inside vim, doing

```
:args * .* **/{*,.*}
```

should work, just like e.g.

```
:args `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
```

There is also `:argadd`, `:argdel`, `:argdo`, `:rewind`, `:next` etc to work with your files.

Comment: Thank you. Could you be so kind as to provide a little more info on what `:args` does.

Comment: @puk: `args *.cpp` does the equivalent of `vim *.cpp` but with vim globbing - comparable to bash's `shopt -s globstar` behaviour. Of course, [`:he arglist`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#arglist) has all the info you could wish for.

Comment: I read somewhere that `:args` overwrites the argument list (which it does not appear to do on my version of vim) that is why I shied away from it in the first place. Instead I stumbled upon `argsadd`.

Comment: @puk: you mean the `:argadd` that I mentioned in `"There is also :argadd, :argdel"`... etc? Ah well, I hope it helped anyway

Comment: sorry I meant `arga[dd]`. Your answer is still correct, I am just splitting hairs here. I was under the impression that `:args` **overwrites** the previous argument list

Comment: @puk: well, you were under the **right** impression then! So does e.g.`vi *`, by the way; Is there a question?

Comment: the question is if I open `vim *.py`, from within vim how can I also add all javascript files? Like so `:arga *.js`?